# how to ask other to merge my repository in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

My senior created a project on gitLab and gave me read only access and asked me to clone it, make changes and submit back to his project in gitLab for his review before merging.

I cloned that repo from gitLab. I created new project with my account on gitLab (of course I have write access on my project) from the earlier cloned repo. I made changes. Now I want to submit repo in my project of my account for review to My senior's project of his account in gitLab

How do I achieve it?

Comment: gitlab has the feature of submitting a merge request (see here: http://gitlab.org/screenshots/). This is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with the same GitLab repo as your senior, in which you have only the right to create a branch, then you would do a [merge request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397116/6309).

But if you are working with a clone of that repo on GitLab side (ie a fork), and you clone locally that fork, meaning you have full access to that GitLab repo, then:

- you push your commit back to your GitLab repo
- you make a [pull request](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/3597) (available since 5.2) between your GitLab repo and the Senior's GitLab repo.