# Is it possible to arrange on your own server mechanism similar to GitHub pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have enterprise project, and I want use pull request mechanism but I can't use cloud service like GitHub or Bitbucket because of the rules of corporate security.
Is it possible to arrange on your own server mechanism similar to GitHub pull request maybe install additional software?

Comment: You can use GitHub Enterprise.  That's self hosted in your own environment.  It expects to run as a VM on some infrastructure though.  Altassian Stash also has similar capabilities.

Comment: I don't understand what is the cost GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: It costs $5,000 per 20 users.  See [here](https://enterprise.github.com/features#pricing) for pricing details.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a local [GitLab server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397116/6309): [it does accept merge requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397116/6309) (similar to pull requests).

you can see more with "[Pull request vs Merge request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22199432/6309)"

Comment: GitLab work on *nix OS, at work, we use C#, Windows everywhere, so I would like a solution on Windows OS. (We installed git server on Windows OS under Cygwin).

Comment: @RinatMullayanov  Sure: use one of your Windows box, add Vagrant (https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-docker-dev-environments.html) and Docker, and you can have a GitLab installation in a few minutes (that you can test and reinstall in seconds). Example http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://qiita.com/k-kagurazaka%40github/items/91f28f6835b3697ed5db&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dgitlab%2Bvagrant%2Bdocker%26client%3Dpalemoon%26rls%3DPalemoon:en-US

Comment: How install Ubuntu on the Vagrant in the Windows 7?

Comment: @RinatMullayanov You need a Virtual box: http://aryannava.com/2014/04/05/installing-vagrant-on-windows-7-and-8/